# How to mimick ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) in R

Tags: r

To manipulate/summarize data over time, I usually use SQL ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by ...). I'm new to R, so I'm trying to recreate tables I otherwise would create in SQL. The package sqldf does not allow OVER clauses. Example table:

```
ID   Day    Person    Cost
1     1        A        50     
2     1        B        25     
3     2        A        30     
4     3        B        75     
5     4        A        35     
6     4        B        100    
7     6        B        65     
8     7        A        20
```

I want my final table to include the average of the previous 2 instances for each day after their 2nd instance (day 4 for both):

```
ID   Day    Person    Cost     Prev2
5     4        A        35     40
6     4        B        100    50
7     6        B        65     90
8     7        A        20     35
```

I've been trying to play around with `aggregate`, but I'm not really sure how to partition or qualify the function. Ideally, I'd prefer not to use the fact that `id` is sequential with the date to form my answer (i.e. original table could be rearranged with random date order and code would still work). Let me know if you need more details, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use OVER with sqldf if you use the PostgreSQL backend.

Comment: It does support that even with the default SQLite backend (unless you are using an old version of the RSQLite package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could lag `zoo::rollapplyr` with a width of 2. In dplyr,

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% arrange(Day) %>%    # sort
    group_by(Person) %>%    # set grouping
    mutate(Prev2 = lag(zoo::rollapplyr(Cost, width = 2, FUN = mean, fill = NA)))
#> Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
#> Groups: Person [2]
#> 
#>      ID   Day Person  Cost Prev2
#>   <int> <int> <fctr> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1      A    50    NA
#> 2     2     1      B    25    NA
#> 3     3     2      A    30    NA
#> 4     4     3      B    75    NA
#> 5     5     4      A    35  40.0
#> 6     6     4      B   100  50.0
#> 7     7     6      B    65  87.5
#> 8     8     7      A    20  32.5
```

or all in dplyr,

```r
df %>% arrange(Day) %>% group_by(Person) %>% mutate(Prev2 = (lag(Cost) + lag(Cost, 2)) / 2)
```

which returns the same thing. In base,

```r
df <- df[order(df$Day), ]

df$Prev2 <- ave(df$Cost, df$Person, FUN = function(x){
    c(NA, zoo::rollapplyr(x, width = 2, FUN = mean, fill = NA)[-length(x)])
})

df
#>   ID Day Person Cost Prev2
#> 1  1   1      A   50    NA
#> 2  2   1      B   25    NA
#> 3  3   2      A   30    NA
#> 4  4   3      B   75    NA
#> 5  5   4      A   35  40.0
#> 6  6   4      B  100  50.0
#> 7  7   6      B   65  87.5
#> 8  8   7      A   20  32.5
```

or without zoo,

```r
df$Prev2 <- ave(df$Cost, df$Person, FUN = function(x){
    (c(NA, x[-length(x)]) + c(NA, NA, x[-(length(x) - 1):-length(x)])) / 2
})
```

which does the same thing. If you want to remove the `NA` rows, tack on `tidyr::drop_na(Prev2)` or `na.omit`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've used dplyr in different tutorials, but I've never really used it for my own "project". Time to dive in